# Can't load a page in a UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios4, uiwebview, nsurl, nsurlrequest

I i'm developing a News App that get the content from a rss feed.
When i click on a TableViewCell I pass a NSDictionary object with the title, link, etc to the next ViewController. In the ViewController I define NSDictionary *item; and I can verify that the values are passed correctly by setting the title of the viewcontroller like this: self.title = [item objectForKey:@"link"]; the title shows the link im trying to open in my UIWebView.

Here is my ViewController's implementation

```
    //
//  NewsDetailViewController.m
//  NewsApp2
//
//  Created by Marco Soria on 12/27/10.
//  Copyright 2010 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "NewsDetailViewController.h"


@implementation NewsDetailViewController

@synthesize item, itemTitle, itemDate, itemSummary;

-(id)initWithItem:(NSDictionary *)theItem{
    if(self = [super initWithNibName:@"NewsDetail" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]){
        self.item = theItem;
        self.title = [item objectForKey:@"link"];
    }

    return self;
}

// The designated initializer.  Override if you create the controller programmatically and want to perform customization that is not appropriate for viewDidLoad.
/*
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization.
    }
    return self;
}
*/


// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *urlAddress = [self.item objectForKey:@"link"]; 

    NSURL *baseURL = [[NSURL URLWithString: urlAddress] retain];        

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:baseURL];

    [self.itemSummary loadHTMLString:urlAddress baseURL:nil];
    [self.itemSummary loadRequest:request];

    [baseURL release];
}


/*
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations.
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
*/

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc. that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];

}


@end
```

Now, when I assign the address like this `@"http://somesite.com"` the UIWebView loads just fine but when i do this: `NSString *urlAddress = [self.item objectForKey:@"link"];`  it never loads. As I mentioned i checked that the value of `[self.item objectForKey:@"link"];` is a valid url since its displaying it in the title of the navigationbar.

if I do this: [self.itemSummary loadHTMLString:urlAddress baseURL:nil];
the UIWebView displays the url, another way of verifying that urlAddress has the correct url.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show the code where you create the new view controller and pass it the item. Show all the code exactly as you have it. You can simply edit your question here and add that code to the end of it.

Comment: Displaying as the title in the navigationbar isn't necessarily evidence of a valid URL. If you NSLog it (or set a breakpoint and po it), what does it look like?

Comment: I NSLog and found that baseURL is returning nil, but urlAddress has a "valid" url so when i do 
NSURL *baseURL = [[NSURL URLWithString: urlAddress] retain];
baseURL is not initializing properly, perhaps it has to do something with encoding ?

Answer (score 0):

Where do you assign `self.title` with `[item objectForKey:@"link"]`?

Have you added `item` as a property of your view controller in your .h file? If you haven't then in your `viewDidLoad` method you posted above, you would not have access to `self.item`.

In your .h file:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController {
    NSDictionary *item;
}
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, retain) NSDictionary *item;
```

In your .m file (adjust this to suit your init method):

```
-(id)initWithItem:(NSDictionary *)item {
    if (self = [super initWithNibName: nil bundle: nil]) {
        self.item = item;   
    }
    return self;
}
```

After you do that you will have global access in your view controller's methods to the `item` property via `self.item`.

Comment: Hi Calvin, as I mentioned above, i did what you just asked me, the problem seems to be that baseURL is not initializing properly even though urlAddress has a valid url

Answer (score 0):

It's solved, i did

```
NSURL *baseURL = [[NSURL URLWithString: [urlAddress stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]] retain];
```

and works now, apparently I was sending some spaces after the url and that's why it wasn't a valid url even though it apeared valid. I NSLog and got baseUrl http://site.com/item.php?id=2458%20%0A%09%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%09%20%20%20%20%09%09%09%09